# Copying an array to a variable whilst excluding items - Performance

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array right here -

```
var children = [Group, Path,Path, CompoundPath,Path];
```

I would like to **copy** the array into a variable, which I do like this

```
var selectionItems = children.slice();
```

Now I would like when copying the array into the variable, to keep in selectionItems only the items that are `Path`'s.

I have tried the `splice()` method but I think it messes up the indices of the copied array which is something I would prefer not to happen. I also have no idea how to exclude anything else other than Path in the new copy of the array.

As always any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var selectionItems = children.filter(function (el) { return el instanceof Path; });
```

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides: I am sorry in that case to quickly assume then.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades I don't think that you misunderstood I just have trouble putting it together.. var selectionItems = children.filter(function (el) { return isPath(el); }); ... Where is the reference to the children array here?  Am I supposed to create the copy first and then do what you suggested on the next line of code?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides This is calling the `filter` method on the `children` object. The children array is the same object referenced in your question. The `filter` method yields a copy, so there's no need to copy anything first, just use it as-is.

Comment: Of course, the `isPath` function is not defined, because I wasn't sure what your `Path` objects actually were. Just replace that with a condition that distinguishes between Path objects and other objects.

Comment: is"Path" ? Is that what you mean?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides What *are* your Path objects?

Comment: @JakeKing Path's from Paper.js http://paperjs.org/reference/path/ I hate to get it this far for you, Isn't the name Path enough to declare a condition that removes them? Do we need to know what they actually are to perform the filtering?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I've updated my answer. Try `instanceof`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54156/discussion-between-nicholas-kyriakides-and-jake-king).